# JTree events seem misordered

Tags: java, swing, events, jtree

It appears to me that tree selection events should happen after focus events, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Assume you have a JTree and a JTextField, where the JTextField is populated by what is selected in the tree. When the user changes the text field, on focus lost, you update the tree from the text field. however, the tree selection is changed before the focus is lost on the text field. this is incorrect, right? Any ideas? Here is some sample code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Focus extends JFrame
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Focus f = new Focus();
  f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  f.setVisible(true);
 }

 public Focus()
 {
  Container cp = getContentPane();
  cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  final JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(5, 10);
  cp.add(new JScrollPane(ta), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane();
  cp.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  JTree t = new JTree();
  t.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener()
  {
   public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent tse)
   {
    ta.append("Tree Selection changed\n");
   }
  });
  t.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
  {
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
   {
    ta.append("Tree focus gained\n");
   }
   public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe)
   {
    ta.append("Tree focus lost\n");
   }
  });

  sp.setLeftComponent(new JScrollPane(t));
  JTextField f = new JTextField(10);
  sp.setRightComponent(f);

  pack();

  f.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
  {
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
   {
    ta.append("Text field focus gained\n");
   }
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe)
{
    ta.append("Text field focus lost\n");
   }
  });
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
}
```

Comment: You should never write code based on the ordering of events.

Comment: You should build the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: I agree with you: it would be more logical if the focus events were triggered before the tree selection event.

Comment: so i shouldn't assume that the windowClosing event will precede the windowClosed event? interesting...

Comment: it's been a while, but can't resist: _i shouldn't assume that the windowClosing event will precede the windowClosed event_ - what a silly remark, except assuming you didn't read the doc ;-)

Comment: i was sarcastically responding to camickr's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Have your text field listener invoke [`setSelectionPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setSelectionPath%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%29) to select the `TreePath` for the node that matches the text. The methods of [`DefaultMutableTreeNode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) can be used to traverse the tree. I'd use an `ActionListener` on the text field, but a `FocusListener` should work—just don't rely on the the order in which `TreeSelectionListener` events arrive.

Here's an example of obtaining the "*pizza*" node in the default `JTree`:

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
TreeNode node = (TreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
node = node.getChildAt(2).getChildAt(1);
TreePath pizza = new TreePath(((DefaultMutableTreeNode) node).getPath());
```

Comment: no you misunderstand, perhaps i didn't explain. Whatever the user types in the text field, on loss of focus, should change the currently selected tree node.

Comment: IIUC, `setSelectionPath()` does exactly that when called from `focusLost()`: it changes the selection to the specified `TreePath`. If you're trying to edit a node, it might be easier to use `t.setEditable(true)`; this would allow editing *in situ*.

Comment: the text field might say 'fooo' but there is no fooo in the tree. in fact it might not even be the node label that is being changed -- it might just be a field in the user object of the selected node.

Comment: It seems easy enough to check each user object while traversing the tree. I typically return null on failure; when passed to `setSelectionPath()`, null clears the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Better news: I tried to defer the tree selection logic to the end of EDT, which will be executed after the text field's focus out!

```
JTree t = new JTree();
t.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener()
{
   public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent tse)
   {
       ta.append("Tree Selection changed\n");
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                logicInEDT...(tse);
            }
       });
    }
});
```

This solution solved my data binding issue. Hope it make sense to you too.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: I got the same issue when I select another tree node. Selecting the same tree node which your text field is editing is fine.

Good news: I found this issue was really old. See 
http://java.net/jira/browse/BINDING-67

Comment: The root reason as you said is TreeSelectionEvent is fired before the focus lost/gained event. And I tested with JTable and JList, both of them works fine, I mean, the selection event is fired AFTER the focus lost of the text field.

Comment: If you are using some data binding framework, I have to say maybe it's good to use MODIFY instead of FOCUS_OUT for the text field's commitment. Anyway, I have to go for this solution for the time being. Sorry, can't help more as that's all I found so far.